# How to prevent being supended?

Tags: discussion, support, sunnah

OH! OH! OH! I'm seeing this line on top of a few users' profiles.

**This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on xx-xx-xx at yy:yy.**

I also find that those who are suspended are really the ones capable of answering questions in a good way. So, if you go on doing this, who else will remain in this site to answer any more?

And also, "**How 'NOT' to get suspended in such a way?**"

Are we given warnings prior to that?

Comment: once I received the warning after being suspended and after I protested for suspending without warning! multiple warning was not true at least for me. actions are different of what is claimed.

Comment: Hmm again that is justifiable I guess, as some people don't consider providing a comment after down voting, I think they didn't consider providing a warning to u...

Comment: Uh, I reckon the moderators ought to be fair against all the users (according to what it is said by @battle of karbala). Since it could be considered as a significant problem if ... practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account suspensions are typically handed out due to consistent and repeated disruptive behaviour, and then typically only after repeated warnings have gone unheeded.  Their ability to answer questions well may factor in the decision, but disruptive behaviour cannot be entirely excused thereby (note also that the most egregiously disruptive examples are often cleaned up by community and/or moderators, so one cannot always judge how constructive a user is based entirely on what remains visible on-site).

From "[A Day in the Penalty Box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)":

> When users exhibit a pattern of either …
>
> ### No effort to learn and improve over time
>
> - This user does not put reasonable effort into the questions they ask of the community.
> - There is little or no evidence of this user learning over time, either in
>     the topic itself or in the community norms on the site.
> - This user intentionally spams the site with the same question or very similar
>     questions, over and over.
> - The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.
>
> ### Disruptive behavior
>
> - Other users tend to react poorly to this user’s contributions, posting negative responses in kind and generally causing a commotion.
> - There is a broad sense of community resentment over this user’s behavior, and they are frequently cited in discussion about the community.
> - There is a dark storm cloud of moderator flags that seems to follow this user around wherever they go.
> - The moderators get email complaints about this user’s behavior.
> - This user makes overtly snide, rude, or hostile comments to their fellow users.
>
> … these problem behaviors *have* to be
>   dealt with. When they aren’t, it takes up excessive moderator time
>   that could be used for something more productive — and, even worse,
>   these behaviors begin to **actively turn people away from our community,
>   stunting its growth and harming everyone.**

Stack Exchange sites are driven by community, and the best way to ensure that you don't get suspended is just to play well with the community.  For the most part, just assuming good faith and following the [general SE guidelines for user behaviour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) is sufficient:

- Be Honest
- Be Nice
- Avoid overt self-promotion

Comment: but timed suspension, is too large. I mean 1 year 2 years is very large time. If he's really passionate about answering here, he/she could create a new id and continue; I think the time should be less.

Comment: @servantofWiser One year suspensions are reserved for the most egregious cases, usually after a repeated and consistent refusal to improve their behaviour even after *multiple* warnings and *multiple* shorter suspensions.  The typical progression is one week->one month->one year.